# how to maintain scroll position on postback in Gridview / Repeater

Tags: c#, .net, repeater

I have a Repeater and when number of data increases the scroll bar is diaplayed.
when i click on any row inside repeater it gets selected and it displays the data correspondingly in next div.
suppose i click on the last record, the data is displayed and row is also highlighted but the scroll goes to its initial position and not last.

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) { ScrolBar();}

private void ScrolBar()
{
    HiddenField PosX = new HiddenField();
    HiddenField PosY = new HiddenField();

    HtmlControl Form1 = this.Master.FindControl("Form1") as HtmlControl;
    PosX.ID = "PosX";
    PosY.ID = "PosY";
    Form1.Controls.Add(PosX);
    Form1.Controls.Add(PosY);

    string script;
    script = "window.document.getElementById('" + PosX.ClientID + "').value = "
              + "window.document.getElementById('" + test1.ClientID + "').scrollLeft;"
              + "window.document.getElementById('" + PosY.ClientID + "').value = "
              + "window.document.getElementById('" + test1.ClientID + "').scrollTop;";

    this.ClientScript.RegisterOnSubmitStatement(this.GetType(), "SavePanelScroll", script);

    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        script = "window.document.getElementById('" + test1.ClientID + "').scrollLeft = "
                + "window.document.getElementById('" + PosX.ClientID + "').value;"
                + "window.document.getElementById('" + test1.ClientID + "').scrollTop = "
                + "window.document.getElementById('" + PosY.ClientID + "').value;";

        this.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "SetPanelScroll", script, true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*For Repeater or GridView try this:
Put control inside div and add an option OnSorting*

```
<div id="divGridView" runat="server" >
    <asp:GridView ID="Grid" runat="server"  OnSorting="Grid_OnSorting"
                OnDataBound="Grid_DataBound" >
```

*on code file add this method:*

```
protected void Grid_OnSorting(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   divGridView.Page.SetFocus(Grid);        
}
```

Comment: This is an old comment and no upvotes and it's the only thing that fixed this issue for me! I put the code in GriidView1_Sorting event at the top. Previously tried various  javascript samples,  and placing the property maintainscrollbackposition = true in page direction.  I'm using master pages withOUT an update panel but I do use divs around the gridview.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put in the following in `Page_Load`:

```
this.Page.MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack = True
```

[Page.MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.maintainscrollpositiononpostback%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use below link using jquery

http://www.sergeyakopov.com/2010/11/easily-maintaining-scroll-position-in-gridview-using-jquery

Comment: Thanks Robby for the link. But i did without using jquery in code behind and it worked like a charm..... :)